# Passing variable from html input to included php file

Tags: php, html, variables, post, checkbox

I have situation where I have an accordian and I am referencing a php file gridlist.php within another php file displayvar.php.  In other words the context of displayvar.php are shown in the webpage gridlist.php.  Now gridlist.php has a checkbox input:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="foodlike" value="icecrm">I like ice cream</input>
 <input type="checkbox" id="foodlike" value="pizza">I like pizza</input>
 <input type="checkbox" id="foodlike" value="soda">I like soda</input>
```

Now when I check on the checkboxes in the table referenced by gridlist.php displayvar.php should be able to display a list of the items checked.  For instance it should display if all three checkboxes are checked:

```
 icecrmpizzasoda
```

If the last one is checked then only soda should be displayed.  Keep in mind because this displayvar.php is displayed within the context of the website gridlist.php I used the following command in gridlist.php:

```
<?php include 'displayvar.php'; ?>
```

I tried in the displayvar.php to obtained the variables foodlike (as defined by the variable id in the checkbox gridlist.php) from gridlist.php and then echo them based on this snippet of code:

```
<?php

   $like=$_POST['foodlike'];
   echo "$like";

?>
```

How can I tweak this code to get my desired result?

Comment: This sounds like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), which you may be approaching the [**wrong way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676). You don't actually need to pass the variables from `gridlist.php` to `displayvar.php`, as `displayvar` is **included** on `gridlist`. What you need to do instead is simply consider all of the code in `displayvar` to also 'exist' in `gridlist`; it will have access to the same variables as `gridlist`. However, if you're using a form submission, you'll either need to use JavaScript or AJAX to update the DOM after a user selection.

Comment: So it is in displayvar.php say echo "$foodlike\n"; I would get the desired results?

Comment: Assuming you are not actually submitting a form, and are trying to output the text as soon as the user makes their selection, you would need to POST the user's selection to the PHP file via AJAX and return the response. If you **are** making use of a form submission back to the same page, `$_POST['foodlike']` is correct, though note that `$_POST` data is tied to the `name` attribute, which you do not currently have. You need `name='foodlike'`. Finally, note that you **cannot** have duplicate `ID` fields - it's **invalid** markup, and you will get **incorrect** data returned!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with :

> gridlist.php

```
<form method="post" action="displayvar.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="icecrm" value="icecrm">I like ice cream</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="pizza">I like pizza</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="soda" value="soda">I like soda</input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

> displayvar.php

```
<?php
    $icecrm = isset($_POST['icecrm']) ? $_POST['icecrm'] : null;
    $pizza = isset($_POST['pizza']) ? $_POST['pizza'] : null;
    $soda = isset($_POST['soda']) ? $_POST['soda'] : null;

    echo is_null($soda) ? $icecrm.$pizza : $soda;
?>
```

Comment: What I am looking for is not having a submit button.  displayvar.php is present within gridlist.php through an include statement.  When I view gridlist.php in a browser I should see the results of displayvar.php which is why I decided to have include displayvar.php.  The thing that should be happening is that the results on displayvar.php should change by checking and unchecking the check boxes in gridlist.php right on the website.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you did not want a submit button, you'll probably want some sort of "interactive", instant solution and bypass going to the server, i.e. bypass PHP. Since the `include 'foo.php'`-statement effectively dumps all contents of foo.php into the current file (you could say it "merges them into one"), all interactions happen *on the same page*. Thinking about your setup as "file A is communicating with file B via the server" is wrong - there is only one file/page.

So, having said all this, my proposed solution uses Javascript and the seemingly omni-present jQuery library, which you will have to include in your page. The snippet below binds an event-handler to the `input`s' `change`-event, which is triggered when a checkbox or radio are checked or the value of a text-input is changed. Then, we append the checked value to a dummy container for display.

```js
$(function() {
  var $likes = $('#likes');


  // bind event handler to all input-elements
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    var $input = $(this),
      oldText = $likes.text();

    if ($input.is(':checked')) {
      $likes.append($input.val());
    } else {
      $likes.text(oldText.replace($input.val(), ''));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="icecream">
  <input type="checkbox" name="icecream" id="icecream" value="icecrm">I like ice cream</label>
<label for="pizza">
  <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" id="pizza" value="pizza">I like pizza</label>
<label for="soda">
  <input type="checkbox" name="soda" id="soda" value="soda">I like soda</label>

<span id="likes"></span>
```

---

**Edit**: This is how I would lay out the "root" file containing the two gridlist.php and displayvar.php, along with the Javascript required to manipulate the DOM:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        label {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- This will be in a file you called 'gridlist.php' -->
<label for="icecream">
    <input type="checkbox" name="icecream" id="icecream" value="icecrm">I like ice cream</label>
<label for="pizza">
    <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" id="pizza" value="pizza">I like pizza</label>
<label for="soda">
    <input type="checkbox" name="soda" id="soda" value="soda">I like soda</label>
<!-- // -->

<!-- This will be in a file you called 'displayvar.php' -->
<span id="likes"></span>
<!-- // -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $likes = $('#likes');

        // bind event handler to all input-elements
        $('input').on('change', function() {
            var $input = $(this),
                oldText = $likes.text();

            if ($input.is(':checked')) {
                $likes.append($input.val());
            } else {
                $likes.text(oldText.replace($input.val(), ''));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit 2**:
You still seem to be having problems, so I shall try to clarify why I *think* you are not succeeding.

Using **only** PHP, it is **not possible** to access the value of a checked checkbox **without** submitting the form back to the server.

To retrieve the value of a checkbox that has been checked by the user, you essentially have **only two possibilities**.

Option 1: **Submit the form using POST/GET**
This entails you having a `<form>` element enclosing the inputs along with a submit button for submitting the form. This is how (probably) 98% of forms on the Internet work. The data in the form is sent, using either the POST or GET method, to the script you specify in the form-tag. Consider this as an example (text omitted):

```
<form action="handler.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the submit-button, the form is sent to `handler.php` via the GET method. There, the form data will be available in the `$_GET` array. Same applies for POST. Now, an often-used approach is to submit the form to *the same script* via `action="#"`, meaning you need not have a dedicated handler, but can process data within the same script as your form. Obviously, you will have to distinguish two cases: one initial case where no data is set in $_GET/$_POST, and one submission-case when the data is set.
The same applies to data stored in the $_SESSION, btw: again, you will have to tell a server-side script to put the data you want in the user-session; only then will you be able to retrieve it again.
A similar approach I would call "Option 1 b)" is submission via AJAX. This is basically form submission without leaving/reloading the page. Sending the data is done via Javascript and an "XMLHttpRequest". An XHR lets you send *any* type of data, not only XML. Again, similar logic applies: you serialize the data in some way, provide an endpoint, usually a script, to talk to, and communicate the data to that script via POST/GET. Then your script can handle the data and return a response, which will be available in the JS that initiated the AJAX-request.

Option 2: **By accessing the DOM directly**
The DOM is the "tree" that is made up of the HTML-elements of your page. Using Javascript, one can access and modify these elements, remove specific ones or add new ones. This API used to be implemented quite differently across browsers, which is why libraries like jQuery or Prototype were created: they provide a unified API across different user agents.
We can use two features of these libraries:

1. respond to (user-triggered) events
2. access elements and data stored therein

This is the approach I used in my answer, which I will not repeat here and you can read above. We respond to the **event** of the user clicking on a checkbox, and **access** that very checkbox to retrieve the **value-data** and process it further.

**TL;DR**
You have two options: submit the form to a script and process the data there; or, manipulate the DOM to catch user-events and pull out the values.

Credit: this is summing up every answer and comment in this thread, especially those of Obsidian Age and Valentin Papin, who both gave great answers that would lead to a clean and functional result.

Comment: I am not clear on something here.  What language is the $(function()  in?  I have tried to replicate this code on my computer with NO success.  Can you be more clear on what you are doing?

Comment: That is a jQuery-shortcut to saying `$(document).ready(function() {...})`. jQuery is a Javascript library for accessing DOM-elements. The code I posted can be put directly in your HTML enclosed in `<script>` tags. Read about jQuery [here](https://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: I am not sure where exactly I should reference the jquery or how to edit it.  Can you show me the specific programming for this?

Comment: In the snippet above, the third section contains HTML. There, you will find, at the very top, a script tag linking to a CDN hosting the library. You can just copy-paste this into your existing HTML, e.g. before the closing `</body>`. I cannot teach you how to use jQuery here, but there are plenty online resources. I suggest you take a look at the documentation to get a feel for what it can do.

Comment: I still cannot find what you are references. What exactly is the line of code I should use?

Comment: I edited my answer, it now contains markup you can copy-paste into a file foo.html that you can open in your browser and it will work. The comments in the HTML refer to the files you included via PHP. Can you build on that foundation?

Comment: The big issue is that I already have a php script that I am referencing.  This php script does some other processes so I need the code tweaked in order so that it can pass the variable off to the php script.

Comment: Well, the solution to the problem you posted has been given twofold, one is the answer by Valentin Papin with form submission, one is mine with DOM-manipulation. Furthermore, comments have pointed out that you need not pass data to files you reference via `include`, as they all share the same scope. If you are unable to apply either of the solutions, I would suggest you post a new question, exactly describing your architecture, what you have done, and what you want to achieve. I'm very much clueless now as to what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: The main point that I am trying to get after is that I need to pass this variable likes to a php script.  I have made several unsucessful attempts in doing so.  This includes trying to call the variable likes in the included php script using $_GET["likes" or $_SESSION["likes"].   My process involves modifying a php script which these paramaters.  Do you have nay idea on how to do this?

Comment: @jms1980, I provided one final edit to my answer. I suggest you re-read the ideas posted in this thread again and try to apply them to your problem. I cannot provide any more assistance than I already have.